# Complex codeigniter user search query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables user, profile and location. The structure of these tables are:

`user` table

```
user_id | email | pass | activated | banned
```

`profile` table

```
user_id | name | birthday | picture | gender | last_active
```

`location` table

```
user_id | city | country | latitude | longitude
```

Now here are search conditions:

1. User must be activated(1) to appear in search result.
2. User must not be banned(0).
3. Search results must be nearby location according to latitude and longitude.
4. search result must order by last active.

To display a search I will need user name, picture, city and country, age, gender and offline/online status.

I have a query to order by location:

```
SELECT 
    latitude, longitude, 
    SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( latitude - 52.58 ) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( - 1.12 - longitude ) * COS( latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) AS distance
FROM 
    location 
ORDER BY 
    distance
```

Can anyone contribute to build a codeignitor query for these conditions?

Comment: When you say a "codeigniter query" do you mean one using their active record class? Because the query you posted above is just a general SQL query and not codeigniter specific.

Comment: Yes I am looking for quesry in active record, I posted genral query to provide clue.. hopw this will help.

Comment: where the status of offline/online store in db, do you know how to search location nearby latitude and longitude

Comment: @Hemant I am taking online/offline by last_active in profile table, I provided genral query to search nearby

Comment: ok, do you know how to search location nearby latitude and longitude

Comment: yes i know but i am looking to implement that query in codeignitor active record based on my tables structure...

Comment: Only benefits you get from using active query is that you don't need to write sql everytime you change the DB and for the sake of simplicity. If you won't change the DB system, I suggest you to just leave it in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try build around this query

```
select l.latitude, l.longitude, 
SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( l.latitude - 52.58 ) , 2 ) +
POW( 69.1 * ( - 1.12 - l.longitude ) * COS( l.latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) as distance
from user as u
left join profile as p
on p.user_id = u.id
left join location as l
on l.user_id = u.id
where u.activated=1 and u.banned=0
order by distance desc
```

May I suggest you lookup using **foreign key** constraints in mysql

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of other optmizations depending on how accurate you need to be and how fast you need it.  I won't show you how to do that right here, but this is the basic codeIgniter query for what you asked:

```
$max_distance = 20;

$this->db
   ->select('*') // Change this to only the fields you need...
   ->select('SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( latitude - 52.58 ) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( - 1.12 - longitude ) * COS( latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) AS distance')
   ->from('user')
   ->where('user.active', 1)
   ->where('user.banned !=', 0)
   ->where('distance <', $max_distance)
   ->join('location','location.user_id=user.user_id')
   ->join('profile','profile.user_id=user.user_id')
   ->order_by('last_active','desc')
   ->get();
```

Please note that distance calculation become slow as soon as you have hundreds of thousands of records.  The most obvious optmization is to first limit the query with a box to cut down on having to calculate the distance for rows that are nowhere near, and then do the radius within that.

Comment: First of all thanks for giving way to provide this. I tried to debug the query but getting error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`user`) JOIN `location` ON `location`.`user_id`=`user`.`user_id` JOIN `pro' at line 2