# MySQL - Conditions with precedence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `terms` with `id, name, school_id and klass_id` as its attributes. I want to return records that satisfies one of the condition. Before I explain the problem in detail, take a look at the table output:

```
id      name    school_id      klass_id
---------------------------------------
1       Term1   NULL           NULL
2       Term2   NULL           NULL
3       Term1   1              4
4       Term2   1              4
5       Term1   1              3
6       Term2   1              3
7       Term1   1              NULL
8       Term2   1              NULL
9       Term1   7              NULL
10      Term2   7              NULL
12      Term1   7              103
13      Term2   7              103
14      term3   7              103
15      Term1   7              30
16      Term2   7              30
17      Term1   7              32
18      Term2   7              32
```

Now, notice that there are three kinds of scenarios here between `klass_id` and `school_id`

1. Both `klass_id` and `school_id` is not `NULL` (condition 1)
2. Only `klass_id` is `NULL` but not `school_id` (condition 2)
3. Both `school_id` and `klass_id` is `NULL` (condition 3)

I'd like to return only those records that satisfies the first condition; if it doesn't, return only those records that satisfies the second condition; if it doesn't return only those records that satisfies the third condition. How do I accomplish this in simple database query?

Comment: What have you tried? What worked or didn't work, and in which ways? (Not only does this show "effort", but it can also be used to showcase correct/incorrect results or specific problems.)

Comment: [I belive its answered][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601148/complex-codeignitor-user-search-query/8607503#8607503

Comment: I've tried using pipe operator. I've heard this somewhere that in computer science, a single pipe('|') operator evaluates an expression that happens to be true, ignoring the rest in the chain. Something like this `SELECT * FROM terms WHERE (klass_id = 25 && klass_id IS NOT NULL) | (school_id = 2 && klass_id IS NULL) | (school_id IS NULL && klass_id IS NULL)`. It works fine for the first 2 conditions, but if the first two conditions are false, for some reason, the 3rd condition just doesn't work

Comment: @Philip - that is a **totally unrelated** question :)

Comment: Hi @Tudor thanks for your response, much apprechiated.  To backup my point I do think its related as my answer shows how to answer complex join questions, ok it may not have been specific but I think generally it relates to the architecture..

Comment: @Philip - then it is related to absolutely any SO question that involves `JOIN`s

Comment: generalisation yes! if you look at his OL of questions, I think my answer complemets it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
    SELECT *, ( SELECT MIN(condition_number) as first_condition_met FROM (
 ( SELECT t.*, 1 as condition_number FROM terms t WHERE ... ) #first condition in WHERE clause
         UNION
       ( SELECT t.*, 2 as condition_number FROM terms t WHERE ... ) #second condition in WHERE clause
         UNION
       ( SELECT t.*, 3 as condition_number FROM terms t WHERE ... ) #third condition in WHERE clause
) ) FROM (
       ( SELECT t.*, 1 as condition_number FROM terms t WHERE ... ) #first condition in WHERE clause
         UNION
       ( SELECT t.*, 2 as condition_number FROM terms t WHERE ... ) #second condition in WHERE clause
         UNION
       ( SELECT t.*, 3 as condition_number FROM terms t WHERE ... ) #third condition in WHERE clause
    ) WHERE condition_number = first_condition_number
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but I get the error `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: My query is just a starting point - syntax errors and concrete `where clauses` still have to be solved/implemented - see [this SO question][1] for the error you are getting


[1][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias]

Comment: @TudorConstantin: Tagged links do not work in comments. You can use this template instead: `[your text](your url)` (works in ‘normal’ posts too).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    terms
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                       ( SELECT *
                         FROM terms
                         WHERE school_id IS NOT NULL
                           AND klass_id IS NOT NULL
                       )
                      THEN 1
                  WHEN EXISTS 
                       ( SELECT *
                         FROM terms
                         WHERE school_id IS NOT NULL
                       )  
                      THEN 2
                  ELSE 3
             END AS result
    ) AS test
WHERE (test.result = 1 
      AND school_id IS NOT NULL
      AND klass_id IS NOT NULL
      )
   OR (test.result = 2 
      AND school_id IS NOT NULL
      AND klass_id IS NULL
      )
   OR (test.result = 3
      AND school_id IS NULL
      AND klass_id IS NULL
      )
```